# Probability/Capacity Problem: Getting in as a club member given external independent factors?

Tags: probability, statistics

**Here's the problem:**

*Current Club members:* 95 out of 100

*Club Remaining Open Capacity:* 5 members

*New Applicants:* 10

**During the application period, here are the factors:**

50% chance that 5 of the current members will quit thus opening some more slots

20% chance that 5 ex-members (priority over applicants) wishes to come back.

**Question:** What are the chances of each applicant to get in the club as a member?

**Notes:**

No one can get rejected except if the capacity is already filled

All applicants have equal chances and independent

All factors are independent

Comment: You don't seem to be trying hard enough to solve this question on your own.

Comment: I am but this is not my major. Im trying to recall my statistics and im trying to solve it as of this writing. Just wanted to make sure that I am solving this the right way.

Comment: @barakmanos would you be able to share any reference similar to this or the methodology? I think I can take it from there. Thanks!

Comment: Hint:  there are four cases to consider.  A. neither factor occurs.  B. only first factor  occurs.  C. only second factor occurs.  D.  both factors occur.  Work out the probability that you are in each of these cases, and the probability that you gain admission given that you are in a particular case.

Comment: @lulu thanks! I think im starting to understand it now.

Comment: I'm having a problem with $5\%$ out of $95$ members quitting, because that will leave us with $90.25$ members.

Comment: @barakmanos sorry about that, there should not be a %. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it into **disjoint** events:

- $0\text{ current members will leave AND 0 previous members will return}$
- $0\text{ current members will leave AND 5 previous members will return}$
- $5\text{ current members will leave AND 0 previous members will return}$
- $5\text{ current members will leave AND 5 previous members will return}$

The corresponding probabilities are:

- $0.5\cdot0.8=0.4$
- $0.5\cdot0.2=0.1$
- $0.5\cdot0.8=0.4$
- $0.5\cdot0.2=0.1$

The expected number of members is therefore:

$0.4\cdot(95-0+0)+0.1\cdot(95-0+5)+0.4\cdot(95-5+0)+0.1\cdot(95-5+5)=93.5$

The chances of each applicant are therefore:

$$\frac{100-93.5}{10}=65\%$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! This completely makes sense. I've been working on this for 3 hours now and I was not able to solve it. I can move on now with my code. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Lyle: Code??? You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if you think it answers your question :)

Comment: Yeah, this is not my major but i requires my to key in some similar function. Sorry im just really bad at statistics. Thanks to you I understand now how it works. :)

Comment: @Lyle: Glad to have helped!